# Создать маску из регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, php, регулярные-выражения

Есть форма в которой пользователь может ввести например номер авто как целиком А333АА123, так и его часть, т.е. А33 или А333АА.
Форма оправляется на бекенд и данный номер может быть там сохранен, как ЧАСТИЧНО так и ЦЕЛИКОМ.
Как на бекенде средствами регулярок и php проверить, что пользователь вводит данные правильно?
Т.е. регулярка равна /^[А-Я]{1}[0-9]{3}[А-Я]{2}[0-9]{3}$/ (упрощена для понимания), но как проверить, что например A33 проходит по данному шаблону?

Answer (score 4):

В упрощённом виде регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так:

```php
/^[А-Я](?:[0-9]{0,3}(?:(?<=[0-9]{3})[А-Я]{1,2}(?:(?<=[А-Я]{2})[0-9]{0,3})?)?)?$/
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/8uXjn5/1).

*Подробности*:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[А-Я]` - одна буква
- `(?:` - начало первой необязательной подмаски:

  - `[0-9]{0,3}` - от нуля до трёх цифр
  - `(?:` - начало второй необязательной подмаски:

    - `(?<=[0-9]{3})[А-Я]{1,2}` - одна-две буквы, перед которыми должно быть три цифры
    - `(?:(?<=[А-Я]{2})[0-9]{0,3})?` - третья необязательная подмаска: от нуля до трёх цифр, перед которыми должны быть 2 буквы
  - `)?` - конец второй подмаски
- `)?` - конец первой подмаски
- `$` - конец строки.

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки части маски можно просто наложить строку на валидный паттерн

```js
const r = /^[А-Я]{1}[0-9]{3}[А-Я]{2}[0-9]{3}$/u;
const pattern = 'Я000ЯЯ000';
const check = s => r.test(s+pattern.slice(s.length));

[
  'ББ12',
  'И7'
].forEach(s => console.log(s, check(s)));
```

На php то же самое написать [несложно](https://3v4l.org/5HCrV).